# Explain Closures in modern javascript

Tags: javascript, closures

I have been learning javaScript lately but I got confused in understanding the concept of closures.How does JavaScript closures actually work ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A  closure gives you access to an outer function’s scope from an inner function
for more info you can follow this link-
http://sleeplessgeek.blogspot.com/2009/12/so-what-are-these-closure-thingys.html

Comment: The paragraph is taken from [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Comment: Please don't answer duplicates. For well-asked questions, please summarize the contents of the link in your answer to prevent your answer from becoming useless in case of link rot [answer].